# blackboxed zone.js in developer tools but still its going into zone.js

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angularjs-directive, zone.js

- I am new to Angular.
- I was debugging below scores method.
- when I step over in developer tools the encoded: true of scores() its going into zone.js.
- I blackboxed zone.js but still its going into zone.js and pointing to this line task.callback.apply(applyThis, applyArgs);
- can you tell me why its going to zone.js eventhough I blackboxed it.
- it would be great if you guys let me know so that in future I can fix it myself.
- providing my code below

**my code**

```or-tag-here
scores() {
    let that = this;
    this.redoCount = 0;
    this.undoCount = 0;
    this.datasourceList = [];
    this.createDatePicker();
    $("#optPlayerDetaileditor").kendoEditor({
        tools: ["bold", "italic", "underline"],
        change: function () {
            that.sportsPlayer.sportsPlayerDetailsText = this.value();
            let eventData = { "eventKey": "optPlayerDetaileditor", "sourceValue": that.sportsPlayerDetailSource, "destinationValue": that.sportsPlayer.sportsPlayerDetailsText, "type": "generateBtn" }
            that.eventCapture(eventData);
            that.sportsPlayerDetailSource = that.sportsPlayer.sportsPlayerDetailsText;
            that.saveBtnEnableDisable();
        }, encoded: true,
        serialization: {
            semantic: false,
            entities: false,
            custom: function (html) {
                return html.replace(/<b>/g, "<B>").replace(/<\/b>/g, "</B>").replace(/<i>/g, "<I>").replace(/<\/i>/g, "</I>").replace(/<u>/g, "<U>")
                    .replace(/<\/u>/g, "</U>").replace(/<br \/>/g, "\n").replace(/&nbsp;/g, " ").replace(/&amp;/g, "&").replace(/&quot;/g, '"').replace(/&gt;/g, ">")
                    .replace(/&lt;/g, "<").replace(/&middot;/g, ".").replace(/&nbsp;/g, " ");
            }
        },
    }).text();
}
```

**zone.js**

```or-tag-here
ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask = function (targetZone, task, applyThis, applyArgs) {
    try {
        return this._invokeTaskZS
                    ? this._invokeTaskZS.onInvokeTask(this._invokeTaskDlgt, this.zone, targetZone, task, applyThis, applyArgs)
                    : task.callback.apply(applyThis, applyArgs);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what do you mean by blackboxing Zone.js. But the method `task.callback.apply(applyThis, applyArgs)` is invoked for calling any scheduled task.

E.g. If you execute `window.setTimeout(cb,1000);`, this will actually call the [monkey patched API](https://github.com/angular/zone.js/blob/1ba851989ccb6907df49bba37ee24ab60adf13a9/lib/common/timers.ts#L62-L102) instead of window.setTimeout. In that API, a new `Task` object is [created](https://github.com/angular/zone.js/blob/1ba851989ccb6907df49bba37ee24ab60adf13a9/lib/zone.ts#L870) with property `callback` initialized with the `cb` passed in `setTimeout` method. Further, the `cb` is replaced by another callback called [timer](https://github.com/angular/zone.js/blob/1ba851989ccb6907df49bba37ee24ab60adf13a9/lib/common/timers.ts#L32) function. Now, when time expires, JS VM will call the callback method of Zone.js i.e. `timer` which will eventually call `task.callback.apply(applyThis, applyArgs)`.

For detailed information on how Zone.js monkey patches API, you can refer below article.

https://medium.com/reverse-engineering-angular/angular-deep-dive-zone-js-how-does-it-monkey-patches-various-apis-9cc1c7fcc321